# How to set a role in DataSource from Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, datasource

I have to use a default Role so that after the datasource has been defined and connected that role will allow me to use select statements. I know its little weird but I have to do it due to security concerns. So here is the code in my Spring's applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:db2://host_name:Port/DB_NAME:INFORMIXSERVER=SERVER_NAME;DELIMIDENT=y;" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
</bean>
```

Everything is fine I am able to connect to the datasource but I also need to tell the database that all the queries will be through this ROLE so that I do have select rights and stuff:
For command prompt I am doing like this:

```
set role ROLE_ACCESS_SELECT;
```

before executing sql commands but don't know how to set it up here.

Please advice.

Answer (score 6):

DBCP's [`BasicDataSource`](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) allows you to pass SQL statements to be executed during initialization of the connection. Something like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name = "connectionInitSqls">
        <list><value>set role ROLE_ACCESS_SELECT</value></list>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I have fixed this issue. Thanks to all who looked at my post the solution is like this:

add this line after  **minIdle** property:

```
<property name="initSQLCommands">
            <list>
                <value>SET ROLE ROLE_WEB_OPERATORS</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

and define a class such as:

```
public class ExtendedBasicDataSource extends BasicDataSource {
    public void setInitSQLCommands(List<String> initSQLCommands) {
        this.initSQLCommands = initSQLCommands;
        setConnectionInitSqls(initSQLCommands);
    }

}
```

And use that bean instead of **org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource** while defining the datasource bean in Spring's ApplicationContext.xml.

Comment: axtavt's suggestion is better, since it doesnt require any extra coding... I think you should flag his response as the answer...

Comment: @HansWesterbeek: Enrique's (self)answer is basicaly the better version of what axtavt is saying (it has correct synthax) and it shows you how to set it programatically if you want. +1