# How to set "SQL_NO_CACHE" default in a pooled mysql JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Our mysql server has "SQL_NO_CACHE" off by default, and I wish it off for my application. I can rewrite all my SQL statements but it sound stupid.

According to the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html) the per connection default can be configure by the following command.

```
SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;
```

I wish this statement will be issues for each new connect created from by DataSource. However, I don't find it is a configurable properties in the connector/j JDBC driver.

[DBCP's connectionInitSqls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198134/how-to-set-a-role-in-datasource-from-spring) seem to be one of the option, but I am using 1.2.2 for some reason. And I may want to remove the dependency of DBCP (less is more).